# Need to add multiple table to word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to add multiple table from the excel macros to a word document.

I have tries it with the object `Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)` via loop but it is overriding the content of existing table with new data.

```
Sub btnrun_Click()
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim ObjSelection
    Dim ObjRange
    Dim objTable
    Dim intRows, intColumns, defVal, x
    Dim y As Integer

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set ObjSelection = objWord.Selection

    intRows = 8
    intColumns = 2
    defVal = 7
    x = 8
    y = 1

    Set ObjRange = ObjSelection.Range
    objDoc.Tables.Add ObjRange, intRows, intColumns

    While (Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x)))
        Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
        objTable.Borders.Enable = True
        objTable.Columns(1).Width = 150
        objTable.Columns(2).Width = 300

    For i = 1 To 1
        For j = 1 To 1
            objTable.cell(j, i).Range.Text = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & defVal)
            objTable.cell(j, 2).Range.Text = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x)
            objTable.cell(j + 1, i).Range.Text = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & 
    defVal)
            objTable.cell(j + 1, 2).Range.Text = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & x)
            objTable.cell(j + 5, i).Range.Text = "Fircosoft UI"
            objTable.cell(j + 6, i).Range.Text = "Cognos UI"
            objTable.cell(j + 7, i).Range.Text = "Database Result"
        Next       
    Next

    x = x + 1                           
    Wend

    objDoc.SaveAs ("D:\PassLogs")
    objWord.Quit

    Set objWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Currently the values are getting overridden but I want them to add in a new table every time.

Comment: With `Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)` you are not creating a new table. You are working with an existing one.  To add tables you will have to use `.Tables.Add`. Do a research on Google on how to add a table in word vba and then use that code in Excel with relevant modifications

Comment: Here is one [example](https://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-add-table-and-fill-data-to-the-word-document/)

Comment: I have done in the same way which you have provided in the example. But it is values are getting overridden in same table.

Comment: What you are doing is adding the table outside the loop. Add the table inside the loop and then work with that. Also instead of `objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns` use `Set objTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(ObjRange, intRows, intColumns)` And then work with the `objTable` :)

Comment: Code is working and 2 tables are created but second table is created withing the first one. Any specific function to break the line and create new table in new line?

Comment: **[Hint]** That is happening because of `ObjRange` in `Set objTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(ObjRange, intRows, intColumns)` Give it a try and we will take it from there...

Comment: Bro, I tried ObjRange.Move to move cursor to next line but isn't working. Please help.

Comment: I can give you the code in one go but that will not help you learn. Do a search in Google on how to insert a table after a table.

Comment: Try something like `vba insert paragraph after table in word` in Google.

Comment: No luck buddy......tried many times but not able to do.

Comment: After the table is created inside the loop, insert a para `objDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter`  and then reset the selection `Set ObjRange = objDoc.Range(objDoc.Content.End - 1)`. These 2 lines will go before `Wend`

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy.....it was really helpful guiding through. Again thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Sid, I am trying to save a word document through excel VBA but it is asking to select the classifier. Can we select the classifier before save it or we can force save without selecting classifier.

Comment: `select the classifier` Sorry I do not understand...

Comment: There are some document classifier like Public, Internal, Confidential and External etc. Before saving the doc we need to choose that for each file that what kind of file is this, public, internal or any other like that.